# How do you responsive align items using Foundation?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, mobile-website

I was wondering if there was an way to align things differently based on whether its a small or large device. Example: I have a button that should right align when its a large screen and then center align on a small screen. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 641px)
{
   .floatleft
  {
    float:left;
  }
}
```

This will make it float left only on small screens. I assume you can use this with float right and any of the other media queries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're laying out your page, and what exactly you mean by "align things differently" but here's a for instance.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='small-3 small-centered large-offset-11 columns'>
        <button>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives you a button that sticks to the right when on a large screen, and moves to the middle on a small screen.

If you were talking specifically about the "align" or "float" property, media queries [(like you said)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24831760/2513895) are the way to go.

Information on the Foundation Grid is [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html).